# View/API for rendering office documents doc,docx, ppt, pptx, xls, xlsx in cocoa application (Mac OSX)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Currently I am developing **cocoa application** for **viewing office documents** inside our application. *"Intention behind this to load documents in-memory and within our app only".*

In iOS application, we are able to render such files using the standard UIWebview class provided with UIKit framework. Hence I tried the same approach with WebView class in mac OSX application. However, it doesn’t work for me.

Sample code used to render files is as below –

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString: filePath];
NSString *mimetype = “mime type of document”;
NSData *filedata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: filePath];
[[webview.mainframe] loadData: fileData MIMEType: mimetype textEncodingName: @”UTF-16” baseURL: url];
```

It displays raw data on screen and not a proper view.

Also tried another approach - **QLPreviewPanel**.
It displays all above formats, but there is no support for passing NSData as input.
Also it provides options like sharing and open document in third party apps.
But we don't require these options and don't allow document to be open in third party apps.

Suggest me better approach for this.

Comment: As far as I know there is no straight forward API for this. WebView does well but not good enough for all document format you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @devgr. UIWebview in iOS application supports all above formats, but strange part is that webview doesn't support these formats.

Comment: You better go with Good for this.